# spawn async process not working with pkexec

Tags: process, glib, stdio, vala, gio

My current gksudo command works with Process.spawn_async_with_pipes. however if I switch gksudo with pkexec it does not show the pkexec window and directly completes the command without the prompt and returns nothing.

When I use Process.spawn_command_line_sync with the same pkexec command it brings up the prompt to ask for the password and the commands executes fine and returns result.

My key reason to use pkexec is to use polkit and not prompt the user for subsequent uses of command which requires root permissions.

My method for Process.spawn_async_with_pipes code is shown below.

I need help in how I can make pkexec work as a background process i.e. the prompt should block the gui but once the user provides the password it should return control back to the gui and continue execution in the background. This is exactly what happens with gksudo.

Thanks in advance

This is the async method

```
public int execute_sync_multiarg_command_pipes(string[] spawn_args) {
        debug("Starting to execute async command: "+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args));
        spawn_async_with_pipes_output.erase(0, -1); //clear the output buffer
        MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
        try {
            string[] spawn_env = Environ.get();
            Pid child_pid;

            int standard_input;
            int standard_output;
            int standard_error;

            Process.spawn_async_with_pipes ("/",
                spawn_args,
                spawn_env,
                SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH | SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
                null,
                out child_pid,
                out standard_input,
                out standard_output,
                out standard_error);

            // capture stdout:
            IOChannel output = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_output);
            output.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
                return process_line (channel, condition, "stdout");
            });

            // capture stderr:
            IOChannel error = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_error);
            error.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
                return process_line (channel, condition, "stderr");
            });

            ChildWatch.add (child_pid, (pid, status) => {
                // Triggered when the child indicated by child_pid exits
                Process.close_pid (pid);
                loop.quit ();
            });
            loop.run ();
        } catch(SpawnError e) {
            warning("Failure in executing async command ["+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args)+"] : "+e.message);
            spawn_async_with_pipes_output.append(e.message);
        }
        debug("Completed executing async command["+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args)+"]...");
        return 0;
    }`
```

This is how it is being called:

```
execute_sync_multiarg_command_pipes({"pkexec", COMMAND_USING_SUDO[6]});
```

Comment: A few things. Are you using Linux or Windows? You may want to check your link. It doesn't _fully_ work for me. Thirdly, why are you using `spawn_async_with_pipes` when the docs you're referencing are for `spawn_async`? Just curious. You ask excellent questions though.

Comment: @oldtechaa Is there even a policy kit port for Windows?

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. a minimal code example that we can have look at).

Comment: @Jens, good point. No idea why I asked that.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I have provided my async method and also the way it is being called.

Comment: This is still not a functional code example, we are missing an example `main ()` and also you didn't provide `spawn_async_with_pipes_output` (which is probably a StringBuilder) and `process_line`.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Many thanks for your response and the complete working example. My async method was correct all the time, however I was calling the method incorrectly. But it took your example to show me the light :-). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning an async pkexec command works:

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
    try {
        string[] spawn_args = {"pkexec", "ls", "-l", "-h"};
        string[] spawn_env = Environ.get ();
        Pid child_pid;

        Process.spawn_async ("/",
            spawn_args,
            spawn_env,
            SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH | SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
            null,
            out child_pid);

        ChildWatch.add (child_pid, (pid, status) => {
            // Triggered when the child indicated by child_pid exits
            Process.close_pid (pid);
            loop.quit ();
        });

        loop.run ();
    } catch (SpawnError e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The prompt comes up and the resulting file listing is from my "/root" directory like expected.

So the problem must be somewhere else.

It also works with pipes:

```
private static bool process_line (IOChannel channel, IOCondition condition, string stream_name) {
    if (condition == IOCondition.HUP) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: The fd has been closed.\n", stream_name);
        return false;
    }

    try {
        string line;
        channel.read_line (out line, null, null);
        stdout.printf ("%s: %s", stream_name, line);
    } catch (IOChannelError e) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: IOChannelError: %s\n", stream_name, e.message);
        return false;
    } catch (ConvertError e) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: ConvertError: %s\n", stream_name, e.message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
    try {
        string[] spawn_args = {"pkexec", "ls", "-l", "-h"};
        string[] spawn_env = Environ.get ();
        Pid child_pid;

        int standard_input;
        int standard_output;
        int standard_error;

        Process.spawn_async_with_pipes ("/",
            spawn_args,
            spawn_env,
            SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH | SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
            null,
            out child_pid,
            out standard_input,
            out standard_output,
            out standard_error);

        // stdout:
        IOChannel output = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_output);
        output.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
            return process_line (channel, condition, "stdout");
        });

        // stderr:
        IOChannel error = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_error);
        error.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
            return process_line (channel, condition, "stderr");
        });

        ChildWatch.add (child_pid, (pid, status) => {
            // Triggered when the child indicated by child_pid exits
            Process.close_pid (pid);
            loop.quit ();
        });

        loop.run ();
    } catch (SpawnError e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even this (which now includes your example code fragment) works:

```
StringBuilder spawn_async_with_pipes_output;

private static bool process_line (IOChannel channel, IOCondition condition, string stream_name) {
    if (condition == IOCondition.HUP) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: The fd has been closed.\n", stream_name);
        return false;
    }

    try {
        string line;
        channel.read_line (out line, null, null);
        stdout.printf ("%s: %s", stream_name, line);
    } catch (IOChannelError e) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: IOChannelError: %s\n", stream_name, e.message);
        return false;
    } catch (ConvertError e) {
        stdout.printf ("%s: ConvertError: %s\n", stream_name, e.message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public int execute_sync_multiarg_command_pipes(string[] spawn_args) {
        debug("Starting to execute async command: "+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args));
        spawn_async_with_pipes_output.erase(0, -1); //clear the output buffer
        MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
        try {
            string[] spawn_env = Environ.get();
            Pid child_pid;

            int standard_input;
            int standard_output;
            int standard_error;

            Process.spawn_async_with_pipes ("/",
                spawn_args,
                spawn_env,
                SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH | SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
                null,
                out child_pid,
                out standard_input,
                out standard_output,
                out standard_error);

            // capture stdout:
            IOChannel output = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_output);
            output.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
                return process_line (channel, condition, "stdout");
            });

            // capture stderr:
            IOChannel error = new IOChannel.unix_new (standard_error);
            error.add_watch (IOCondition.IN | IOCondition.HUP, (channel, condition) => {
                return process_line (channel, condition, "stderr");
            });

            ChildWatch.add (child_pid, (pid, status) => {
                // Triggered when the child indicated by child_pid exits
                Process.close_pid (pid);
                loop.quit ();
            });
            loop.run ();
        } catch(SpawnError e) {
            warning("Failure in executing async command ["+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args)+"] : "+e.message);
            spawn_async_with_pipes_output.append(e.message);
        }
        debug("Completed executing async command["+string.joinv(" ", spawn_args)+"]...");
        return 0;
    }

public static int main (string[] args) {
    spawn_async_with_pipes_output = new StringBuilder ();
    execute_sync_multiarg_command_pipes ({"pkexec", "ls", "-l", "-h"});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. my code was working all the time. I was invoking the execute_sync_multiarg_command_pipes method incorrectly ! I have accepted your answer above. Since its a complete example, it might help someone trying to use the async method